# Overriding CSS in discrete charts in angular nvd3

Tags: javascript, angular-nvd3

I am working angular nvd3 charts, i override the css of nv.d3.min.css

```
.nvd3 text {
font : 400 12px Arial;
font-weight: 300 !important;
}
```

It worked fine but when i clicked the grouped to stacked or vice-versa , my overridden css don't work.

Can anybody help me how to provide dynamic css when ever charts change i can handle that event and my css changes reflects.

Comment: D3 may be adding styling as it appends the svg elements, have you tried changing the styling in javascript after you add them to the page?

Comment: that's what i am asking , can you tell at what code library makes chart again and on which event, so that i can write my code exactly at the same poisition